# How to change the color of a part of title in matplotlib plots while using f string?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, classification, image-classification

I want to change some parts of title for a plot in matploblib while I'm using f string for the title, this is my title:

`plt.title(f"Predicted: {class_names[y_pred_class]} | Confidence: {torch.softmax(y_pred, dim=1).max().item():.2f}")`

I have a variable named `color` which is green if the model predict correct:

```
if class_names[y_pred_class] == img_class:
      color = 'green'
else:
      color = 'red
```

I want to change the color of `class_names[y_pred_class]` to variable `color`

how should I do this?